# Random numbers, small decimals

Tags: python, random, spyder

I'm working with random numbers in python, the problem is the following;
I have a variable, we can call it "x", I want it to take values between [10^-6,10^-1], then I have the following line

```
x=np.random.uniform[1e-6,1e-1]
```

But it is only generating numbers like

```
0.123123  0.524234   0.0453454  0.9083405
```

It never generates numbers like

```
0.0002342  0.00002434  0.313123  0.000004234  0.034234
```

How can I generate the second type of random numbers? Generating random numbers of magnitudes `1e-1,1e-2,1e-3,1e-4,1e-5,1e-6`?

Comment: You can add another randomizer that will takeaway a couple of numbers from the previously generated number.

Comment: It's a uniform distribution. Perhaps the scaling is fooling you. Picture instead, e.g., generating integers uniformly at random from, say `range(1000000)`. Then it should be obvious that the chance of getting a result < 10 is 10x less than the chance of getting one < 100, which is in turn 10x less than getting one < 1000, ..., and, in fact, half the results will be at least half of 1000000. Nothing essential about that changes by throwing decimal points in; e.g., you should _expect_ half your results to be >= 0.45, and so on. "Very few" will be "very small".

Comment: Perhaps you are looking for logarithmically distributed numbers (uniformly random in the power of 10), so perhaps generate random numbers between -6 and -1 and then calculate 10**r?

Comment: @TimPeters  can you check what I did, what do you think about it?

Comment: @JonathanDrukker What do you think about my answer?

Comment: @chthonicdaemon I think you were right.

Comment: @FelipeVillazon I've posted an answer based on the above comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that you are looking for logarithmically distributed data, where the log of the statistic is uniformly distributed. Knowing this you can construct these numbers easily:

```py
import numpy as np

exponent = np.random.uniform(-6, -1, 10000)
x = 10**x
```

A histogram of x looks like this:

[image: histogram of x]

while a histogram of the log of x (which is equal to the exponent by construction) looks nice and uniform:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you are calling the function in the right way, but you can use an alternative custom function such as:

```
import numpy as np

def myRandomUniform(max_value, min_value):
    return (max_value - min_value)*np.random.uniform() + min_value
max_value = 1e-1
min_value = 1e-6
x = myRandomUniform(max_value, min_value)
```

**Edit:**
I made an histogram 1.000.000 random numbers and it looks like it is generating the small values that you want.
[Histogram using random function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ewbgD.png)

Comment: Thanks for your time, can you check what I just posted, what do you think?

Answer (score 0):

I probably found a way to make it better, if we make a histogram of `np.random.uniform(1e-6,1e-1)`, at first it will be very uniform of course, but the point here is to make a histogram of the log10 of the data, that is,

```
data=[np.log10(np.random.uniform(1e-6,1e-1))for _ in range(100000)]
plt.hist(data)
```

it is gonna give us
https://i.stack.imgur.com/rgMKQ.png
which is clearly not uniform. Then I defined the following function

```
def ram(Min):
x=np.random.choice([Min,Min*1e1,Min*1e2,Min*1e3,Min*1e4])
r=np.random.uniform(0.01*x,10.1*x)
return(r)
```

if we make a histogram,

```
data = [np.log10(ram(1e-6)) for _ in range(100000)]
plt.hist(data)
```

It is gonna gives us,
https://i.stack.imgur.com/jxpeQ.png
which is clearly between `1e-6 and 1e-1` more uniform.

The goal now is to improve that function.

Here is the comparison between the histograms.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/SXPWk.png